# Using Nuget to get jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I am new to ASP.NET, though not to web programming (I used PHP until now). Working on my first ASP.NET project (actually, maintaining an existing one) I wanted to use jQuery. I had heard that it is so easy to use in VS2010 - just install it with Nuget and use it. So I installed it with Nuget and now I can't figure out how to use it!

How to I actually get it to be available in my HTML? It seems to just be sitting there in a Scripts folder doing nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you are using Visual Studio 2010, the default application templates already contain jQuery, so there isn't any need to use NuGet.

Just add a reference of the jQuery script to the page you need, and you are good to go:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

[image]

For IntelliSense: Also add `jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js`.

[image]

Comment: Which one? (vsdoc, min, regular)

Comment: True, they get you started, but if you utilize nuget with the jQuery libraries, it will notify you and streamline the upgrade process whenever new version of jQuery are available

Comment: BTW, jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js is for intellisence support in VS...So, you can add that also.

Comment: @KPL Still not getting Intellisense :(

Comment: Worth mentioning: If you are using ASP.NET's script bundling capabilities (available in MVC 4 project types, and I *think* available for traditional ASP.NET web forms) you get an additional benefit where NuGet will auto update your package.config file with the latest library version number. More on script bundling here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 2):

Just add a reference to the script you want to use on the page you need it on, for example, in the head-tag:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Of course, the `src` should be relative to your page and the script.

---

If you are using ASP.NET MVC and the Razor-engine, you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
```

Ideally, you would add this to the `_layout` file in the `Views > Shared` folder. That way it turns up on all pages (views).

Answer (score 1):

NuGet simply downloads the jQuery library. You need top drag the script file(s) to your pages and VS will automatically create a script reference of the form:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery... />
```

And you can start using it then.

Comment: And I will get the famous Intelisense?

Comment: Yes, you should because you are using VS2010

Comment: I am not getting Intelisense

Answer (score -2):

If your question is how to get JQuery in your html, Simply add a script tag in the head of your HTML, since your using VS2010, you should be able to drag-and-drop the script file into the HTML file, it will create the script tag